# How to load classes from jar files which some of the classes in a one jar depends on the classes in the other jar file

Tags: java, class, jar, dependencies

Let's say that there are two jar files where one jar file contains java interfaces that are used by the classes in the other jar file. If, I load all the classes inside both the jar files into the class loader does the class dependencies are solved at the run-time? Or, else is it possible to do this task with out using any other third party libraries.

Comment: The interface jars need to be loaded in either parent class loader or the same class loader, but otherwise yes...